# Process Vector is input's neural of Input Layer of Neural network

Tags: c#, java, c++, matlab, face-detection

I'm researching Face Detection using Neural network and PCA (Principal component analysis), but I have a problem with the Input Layer of the Neural Network:

After using PCA to process the image face database, I have a set of EigenVectors (1 Image face = 1 Vector).

According to the Neural Network documentation, the input layer only accepts real values (e.g. 0.1, 1, 100, 10000). But in case the input's are vectors, so I can't process in this step.

Answer (score 0):

Vector - an ordered set of numbers in your case. Right? The input layer of the neural network can also be considered as a vector. Both vectors must be the same length. So you should first element of the vector apply to a first input of the input layer network, the second element of the vector - the second input, and the third - the third input, ..

Comment: Thank you Dmitry.
But if we train one vector per time and then apply " back propagation " to update weights of neural network, we must train n times ( n is a numbers of image face database - vectors ) and we have n set weights.
This perhaps is a real way or...I misunderstand about neural network.

Comment: Do not mention it. Network training is based on a sample - the database of vectors. That the base has 'n' vectors and the network has 'n' inputs - may be just a coincidence. How long these vectors? I think the same length 'n'. You should apply the components of these vectors to the corresponding input of network. Post a vector to one input of the network is not possible. In this picture x1,x2,...,xn are components of your vector: http://tracer.lcc.uma.es/problems/ann/ann-Dateien/aneurona.jpg